# Unitary testing: emulating hardware connection or disconnection

Tags: qemu, testing, emulation

I'm writing a program using libudev. And I want to write some tests. But, one of the functionalities of the program has to do with an usb drive being connected or disconnected.

I've read plenty of documentation about `qemu` and its many many applications. But I'm still without find the way for correctly write unitary tests that have to do with connection or disconnection of hardware to the pc.

Which the best (or easiest) way of accomplish this?